# Magento 2 - How to use jQuery in CMS page

Tags: magento2, jquery, cms-pages

how to add  cms home page jquery in magento 2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   $(".home-banner").insertBefore(".page-main");

 });
```

Please advance thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $(".home-banner").insertBefore(".page-main");
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's working now so thanks for help @hweb87

Comment: This also works in CMS Blocks

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Share with me your console screenshot

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `domReady!` so that it only loads if the DOM is ready:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
        ,'domReady!'
    ], function ($) {
        $(".home-banner").insertBefore(".page-main");
    });
</script>
```